# .NET CORE Dictionary<string, object> does not consume post request parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have recently migrated to .NET Core from .NET Framework,

My controller parameters usually contains Dictionary<string, object> to handle payload request which are in JSON Format .

```
public JsonResult RegisterUser(Dictionary<string, object> reqInfo)
```

However upon trying this on .NET Core the dictionary is always null although my request payload has values.

Comment: We need more info here. Do you have more code you can share, particularly any request method attributes on RegisterUser? Have you confirmed that this method runs, and is getting null for reqInfo or is the endpoint not being hit at all?

Comment: JSON is text so a `Dictionary<string,object>` won't help. Besides, what happens if the string contains an *array*?  You don't need a *dictionary* to handle JSON in the first place. You can use a strongly typed object. That's how all ASP.NET Core projects, all docs and tutorials work. Even if you want to handle arbitrary JSON payloads with a single action, it's better to use `dynamic` instead of `Dictionary`.

Comment: Please post the JSON text. It's quite possible the request contains a JSON array, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to specify an attribute to the payload's source.

According to the Microsoft Docs, the payload is scanned for potential sources but "only for simple types."

So if your payload source is the body, try using the following code:

```
public JsonResult RegisterUser([FromBody] Dictionary<string, object> reqInfo)
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#sources

Comment: And even that will fail if the body contains an array.

Comment: I have tried this one but it reflects as a stringified array.

Comment: Will there be a way to pass a multi dimensional array ?